# List letters at even- or odd-numbered positions in Alphabet

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

To make a list of the letters at even-numbered position in Alphabet, I wrote this code:

```
Select[Alphabet[], EvenQ[Flatten[Position[Alphabet[], #]]] &]
```

But it does not work. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: As one begins learning *Mathematica* executing smaller parts of the overall function will give strong hints as to what might not be working as expected/desired.  For example, `Flatten[Position[Alphabet[], "a"]]` gets you `{1}` and not `1`.

Comment: @JimB But EvenQ[{1}] will show [False]. So, it shouldn't influence the answer.

Comment: With that you get `{False}` and what you need is just plain `False`.

Comment: How about `Select[Alphabet[], EvenQ[Flatten[Position[Alphabet[], #]]][[1]] &]`.

Comment: @JimB Thank you. You are so clever. Should I close the question. I fear somebody will vote this question to close.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit 's answer is the more straightforward approach.

Comment: Also explore: `CharacterRange`. It doesn't work like `Range` as it does not accept an increment so you have to resort to `Span` as shown in the answer.

Comment: crossposted: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2471931

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Much simpler solution:

```
Alphabet[][[1 ;; All ;; 2]]
Alphabet[][[2 ;; All ;; 2]]
```

Comment: `Alphabet[][[1 ;; ;; 2]]` is equivalent and slightly shorter.

Answer (score 3):

Using `LetterNumber` and `FromLetterNumber`

**1.**

If all letters are different we can create an `Association`

```
asc = AssociationThread[#, LetterNumber @ #] & @ Alphabet[];

Keys @ Select[OddQ] @ asc
```

{"a", "c", "e", "g", "i", "k", "m", "o", "q", "s", "u", "w", "y"}

```
Keys @ Select[EvenQ] @ asc
```

{"b", "d", "f", "h", "j", "l", "n", "p", "r", "t", "v", "x", "z"}

```
Keys @ Select[Mod[#, 4] == 0 &] @ asc
```

{"d", "h", "l", "p", "t", "x"}

**2.**

If there are duplicated letters we can use `Cases`

```
list = {"c", "a", "b", "b", "c"}

Cases[LetterNumber @ list, x_?OddQ :> FromLetterNumber[x]]
```

{"c", "a", "c"}

```
Cases[LetterNumber @ list, x_?EvenQ :> FromLetterNumber[x]]
```

{"b", "b"}

Answer (score 2):

Using the third argument of `GroupBy`:

```
Values@GroupBy[Thread@{Range@Length@#, #} &@Alphabet[], OddQ, Last /@ # &]

(*{{"a", "c", "e", "g", "i", "k", "m", "o", "q", "s", "u", "w", "y"},
 {"b", "d", "f", "h", "j", "l", "n", "p", "r", "t", "v", "x", "z"}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using `MapIndexed` with `Sow`/`Reap`:**

```
MapIndexed[If[OddQ@*First@#2, Sow[#, "odd"], Sow[#, "even"]] &, 
   Alphabet[]] // Reap // Last
```

**Using `PositionIndex`:**

```
PositionIndex[Alphabet[]] // GroupBy[OddQ@First@#1 &] // 
  Map[Keys] // Values
```

or

```
PositionIndex[Alphabet[]] // 
  GroupBy[#, OddQ@First@#1 &, Keys] & // Values
```

---

*Result:*

> {{"a", "c", "e", "g", "i", "k", "m", "o", "q", "s", "u", "w",    "y"},
> {"b", "d", "f", "h", "j", "l", "n", "p", "r", "t", "v", "x",    "z"}}

Answer (score 1):

I've used Range to determine the sequence.

`Alphabet[][[Range[1, 26, 2]]]` for odd positions,
for even positions `Alphabet[][[Range[2, 26, 2]]]`

Comment: This appraoch is very similar to the one already given.

Answer (score -1):

Extending (slightly) the neat [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/263640/106) by @Sjoerd Smit:

```
Alphabet[odd]  ^:= Alphabet[][[1 ;; All ;; 2]]
Alphabet[even] ^:= Alphabet[][[2 ;; All ;; 2]]


Alphabet[odd]
Alphabet[even]

(* 
   {"a", "c", "e", "g", "i", "k", "m", "o", "q", "s", "u", "w", "y"} 
   {"b", "d", "f", "h", "j", "l", "n", "p", "r", "t", "v", "x", "z"}     
*)
```

Similarly:

```
Alphabet[vowels]   ^:= Alphabet[][[{1, 5, 9, 15, 21}]]
Alphabet[noVowels] ^:= Alphabet[][[{2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 
                         18, 19, 20, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26}]]

Alphabet[vowels]
Alphabet[noVowels]

(* {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u"}

   {"b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "q",
    "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"}

*)
```